# Active directory azure, handle sign in "access_denied" error using custom error page?

Tags: authentication, azure, active-directory

I have got below error while sign in the user who is not assign to the webapp. I want to display custom error page instead of this.

An error of type 'access_denied' occurred during the login process: 'xyz121': User account is disabled.
Trace ID: xyz121
Correlation ID: xyz
Timestamp: 2015-05-18 05:51:16

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: This isn't really an Azure Active Directory question as handling this error will be done in your user interface.  Could you please post the code from the part of your application that is handling the login event, and change the tags on this question to reflect that?